# How to calc() the number of rows in a grid template?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, css-calc

I'd like to calculate the number of rows in a grid template using `calc()`, but trying to get the `repeat` count with division isn't working:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.grid>div {
  background: tomato;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid.no-calc {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 30px);
}

.grid.addition {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(calc(1 + 2), 30px);
}

.grid.subtraction {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(calc(4 - 1), 30px);
}

.grid.multiplication {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(calc(3 * 1), 30px);
}

.grid.division {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(calc(6 / 2), 30px);
}
```

```html
<p>Top 4 have their row heights set correctly</p>

<div class="grid no-calc">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid addition">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid subtraction">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid multiplication">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<p>Division doesn't work in setting row height</p>

<div class="grid division">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Is there something I'm missing about the way `repeat`, `calc`, and division work together? This is in Chrome 71.0.3578.98.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using division with `calc` the result will be a `number` and not an `integer` thus it won't work because the `repeat()` expect an `interger`

> The generic form of the `repeat()` syntax is, approximately,
>
> `repeat( [ <positive-integer> | auto-fill | auto-fit ] , <track-list> )`<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#funcdef-repeat)</sup>

And

> At `/`, check that the right side is `<number>`. If the left side is `<integer>`, resolve to `<number>`. Otherwise, resolve to the type of the left side.<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation)</sup>

And

> Number values are denoted by `<number>`, and represent **real numbers**, possibly with a fractional component.<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#number-value)</sup>

Even if we both know that the result will be an integer the browser will still consider it as a number.

You can have the same issue with multiplication in case you have a number in one of the sides

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.grid>div {
  background: tomato;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid.no-calc {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30px);
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
}

.grid.multiplication {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(3 * 1.0), 30px); /*will fail*/
  border-bottom:calc(3px * 1.0) solid red;
}

.grid.division {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(6 / 2), 30px);
  border-bottom:calc(6px / 2) solid red; /*this will work because border accept numbers*/
}
```

```html
<div class="grid no-calc">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>


<div class="grid multiplication">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="grid division">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

---

Firefox is behaving differently and never fail even if we explicitely specify numbers. In all the cases Fiferox will *try* to round the result of `calc()` to a positive integer one.

All the examples below will fail on Chrome and will work on Firefox:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.grid>div {
  background: tomato;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid.no-calc {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(2.8), 30px); /*will be converted to 3*/
  border-bottom:calc(calc(2.8) * 1px) solid red;
}

.grid.multiplication {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(3 * 1.55), 30px);  /*will be converted to 4*/
  border-bottom:calc(calc(3 * 1.55) * 1px) solid red;
}

.grid.division {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(6 / 2.8), 30px); /*will be converted to 2*/
  border-bottom:calc(calc(6 / 2.8) * 1px) solid red;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="grid no-calc">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>


<div class="grid multiplication">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>

<div class="grid division">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that! Is there any way to convert a CSS number to an integer?

Comment: @SanderMoolin Not that I'm aware of. It's certainly something to bring up to the WG, though!

Comment: @SanderMoolin actually not, but it would be intresting to have a floor() or round() function .. probably in a future level ;)