# CSS Calc() division returns works weird inside a repeat() function inside grid-template-columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I am creating a css grid of squares that needs to fill the whole page, and every square needs to be 60px exactly.

So I was trying to use calc() to get the quantity of items I should render in each row (number of columns) so I don't get extra overflow out of the screen.

**The problem**: CSS calc() works in some cases and does not work in other cases.

**Some examples:**

- grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(1), 60px);      // work
- grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(10*2), 60px);   // work
- grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(10*0.5), 60px); // does not work
- grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(100/60), 60px); // does not work

I though it was because the repeat() function need an integer as first parameter, but `calc(100/10)` does not work either.

Actually, `calc(100 * calc(1/2))` and `calc(100*calc(10/2))` also didn't work.

This was my original code or what I wanted to do:

```
 .grid-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( calc(1024 / 60), 60px); 
    grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 60px); 
    grid-row-gap: 2px;
    grid-column-gap: 2px;
}
```

EDIT: I think the best answer is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447832/how-to-calc-the-number-of-rows-in-a-grid-template).

> When using division with `calc` the result will be a `number` and not an `integer` thus it won't work because the `repeat()` expect an `interger`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Grid Layout Module - Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#repeat-syntax) (official documentation), the first parameter of repeat has to be a ***positive integer***.

According to Values and Units Module - Level 3, [`calc()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation) should be allowed here, as it...

> ... can be used wherever `<length>`, `<frequency>`, `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<percentage>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` values are allowed.

The spec does not specify what the behavior of `calc()` should be if the result is different than what the property expects. All we know is that it is *"invalid"*, so it's up to the browser to decide how to treat invalidity cases.

So far, the friendliest browser is Firefox, which rounds a `calc()`s result up to nearest integer when used in `grid-template-*`'s `repeat()`.
It is probable Chrome will do the same, but, for now, the safest route seems to be using JavaScript to calculate the positive integer dynamically on page load and resize (and write the `grid-template-columns` value accordingly).

Comment: Using `calc()` seems to work fine - in Chromium 71/Ubuntu 18.10 - as the first argument to `repeat()`, with the exception of division: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xg59t1uy/1/).

Comment: (Although in Firefox even the division works).

Comment: @DavidThomas have you tried `calc(100*0.5)` or something that returns a possible float?

Comment: If the result of `calc` is a positive integer, you should expect it to work in all browsers supporting `calc`. If it's not and works in a particular browser, it means that browser automatically parses a positive integer from your result. That is not part of the specification and it's not likely to work in other browsers. It's more likely to be dumped from the ones in which currently works, to be exact.

Comment: Do note the official specification has a status of "Draft". More than likely the spec will be consolidated into clearer rules. Once that's done, expect most browser to align to the Recommendation version of the spec.

Comment: @sujumayas, just now: yes and, in Firefox (65/Ubuntu 18.10) it works (in Chromium it fails miserably). [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xg59t1uy/2/).

Comment: @DavidThomas So I suppose is more of a "Browser support thing" depending on how they render the result of the calc() function. Because positive integers as a result of `calc(100/60)` did not work in chrome.

Comment: @DavidThomas a division will always be evaluated to a *number* and not an *integer* even if we know that the result is an integer ... same logic if we do `100*0.5`, so it will fail and technically it should fail in Firefox also ... but it's seems that firefox is converting number to integer or violating the spec of calc

Comment: @sujumayas the result will be a positive *number* not a positive *integer* .. from our perpective it's the same, but  for the browser they are different

Comment: @DavidThomas and more intresting, Firefox seems to also round number .. so if you try `calc(10 / 4)` which is equal to `2.5`, it will get rounded to `3`.

Comment: This, @Temani, is one of those times where I think deviating from the spec makes more sense than adhering to it (especially given there’s no equivalent of `Math.floor()`, or `parseInt()` in CSS).

Comment: @DavidThomas, in the long run, and in principle, all deviations from spec are costly. Browsers pay the cost in market share and developers in time (hence money). In this case, say you're using FF as dev browser and you don't notice it fails in other browsers. In most cases, it will cost you more to fix it than it would have if FF wasn't "helpful" in the first place.

Comment: @Andrei: agreed (to a point), but one of the means by which a spec is developed and improved is by implementation of non-spec properties (`scroll-snap` as an example) or deviation from the spec (although I can’t think of an example to back that up). But I do prefer Firefox’s implementation. As for the problem of developing in Firefox and not noticing its nonstandard behaviour? That’s on the dev for not testing adequately.

Comment: My point is that any delay is detecting a problem is costly, even when testing "properly". Some more than others. And our discussion, while enjoyable, has gone increasingly off-topic. Sorry about that.