# How to convert a CSS grid track from pixels to fr unit?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I want to know if possible to convert a CSS grid template track from pixels to fr.
In example, I have a DIV element with 1894px of width and 200px of height with a class `.grid`

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 1894px;
    min-height: 200px;
    grid-template-columns: 1196px 100px repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr repeat(3, 0.5fr) 1fr;
    margin: 10px;
    gap: 0px;
}
```

So I want to know to how convert the value **1196px** of first track of `grid-template-columns` to fr.

Also, what happens in case the gap is greater than 0?

In Chrome DevTools when search the expected value manually I get `1196px` when changing the track value to `4fr` and then check values in the Computed tab, but, how I can get this value in Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You want to have `grid-template-columns: xfr 100px repeat(2, 1fr);` so the formula will be:

```
width_container = 100px + 3*gap + (x + 2)*F With  x*F = 1196px
```

in your case you will have

```
1894px = 100px + (x + 2)*F
1794px = (x + 2)*F
```

we do a division and we get:

```
1.5 = (x + 2)/x
1.5 = 1 + 2/x
x = 4
```

The generic formula in your case can be written as:

```
(width_container - 100px - 3*gap)/1196 = 1 + 2/x
x = 2/(A/1196px - 1) where A = (width_container - 100px - 3*gap)
```

Below an illustration of the calculation. Note how the `alt` row are similar to the previous ones. Not exactly the same in some cases due to the rounding we need to do since [`repeat` accept only integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447986/8620333)

```js
$('.grid:not(.alt)').each(function() {
   var w = $(this).width();
   var g = parseInt($(this).css('gap'));
   var A = w - 100 - 3*g;
   
   var x = Math.round(2/(A/1196 - 1));
   $(this).next('.alt').css("grid-template-columns",x+"fr 100px repeat(2, 1fr)");
   console.log(2/(A/1196 - 1) +"("+x+")");
})
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 1894px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  grid-template-columns: 1196px 100px repeat(2, 1fr);
  margin: 10px;
  gap: 0px;
}

i {
  display:block;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
}
i:first-child {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
<div class="grid alt" style=""><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>

<div class="grid" style="gap:100px;"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
<div class="grid alt" style="gap:100px;"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>


<div class="grid" style="gap:50px;"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
<div class="grid alt" style="gap:50px;"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>

<div class="grid" style="width:1900px;"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
<div class="grid alt" style="width:1900px;"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
```